# Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))

Tags: visual-studio-2012, dll, hresult

I have a project which runs in visual studio 2008. When I try to convert the project within visual studio 2012 (on a different computer) I get the following error:

Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))

I have included all references and do not know where I am going wrong. I have one reference which is a third party .dll - it has a prefix ax. I also have references to AxInterop.MSCommLib.dll and Interop.MSCommLib.dll. I have tried setting the target platform to x86 and this does not solve this issue. I have also tried registering the .dll files but get the following:

The module "interop.mscommlib.dll" was loaded but the entry-point DllRegisterServer was not found

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: There are hundreds of questions about this error already.  They all have the same answer, surely you too forgot to deploy and register MSComm32.ocx on the target machine.  Don't use ancient VB6 controls, use the .NET SerialPort class instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use dependency walker to find if DllRegisterServer doesn't exist or if it exists with a C++ name. It should have a C name.

This function registers a COM DLL in the registry.

Since it worked before, you probably not linking with something.